# Lazy loading/react-loadable in React-on-Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, lazy-loading, react-loadable, react-on-rails

I want to lazy load all of my top-level components to improve load time. I am using [react-on-rails](https://github.com/shakacode/react_on_rails) to integrate React and Ruby on Rails. To render the components, I have to register them like so in `registration.jsx`:

```
import ReactOnRails from 'react-on-rails';
import Component1 from '../components/Component1';
import Component2 from '../components/Component2';

ReactOnRails.register({Component1, Component2});
```

I tried two methods:

### **1. React.lazy:**

```
import {lazy} from "react";
const Component1 = lazy(() => import("../components/Component1"));
```

But the browser throws an error...

```
Uncaught Error: Module build failed: SyntaxError: 
.../app/registration.jsx: Unexpected token, expected ";" (20:113)
```

It seems that I cannot use lazy load in this file. So I tried it in a sub component within Component1. But it still doesn't work.

```
 const SubComponent = lazy(() => import("./SubComponent"));
```

This returns:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: SubComponent is not defined
```

### **2. react-lodable:**

[Official doc](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable)

This seems to be recommended by `react-on-rails` (see below), but I got a different error saying react-on-rails cannot find such components.

```
import ReactOnRails from 'react-on-rails';
import Loadable from "react-loadable";

const loading = () => {
  return <div>Loading...</div>;
}

const Component1 = Loadable({
  "loader": () => import('../components/Component1'),
  "loading": loading
});

import Component2 from '../components/Component2';

ReactOnRails.register({Component1, Component2});
```

This is the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ReactOnRails encountered an error while rendering component: Component1.
Original message: React is not defined
```

I tried to use it on a sub-component, too. But it just doesn't render it.

```
import Loadable from "react-loadable";

const loading = () => {
  return <div>Loading...</div>;
}

const SubComponent = Loadable({
  "loader": () => import("./SubComponent"),
  "loading": loading
});

class Component1 extends PureComponent {
  render () {
    return (
      <SubComponent />
    )

  }
}
```

But this only returns "loading..."

### **Questions:**

The only good news is that Webpack is correctly splitting the bundles into smaller bundles based on components, so I think `react-loadable` works, but was not rendered correctly.

Is it possible to lazy load components using `react-on-rails`? Or am I having a syntax error? It seems that `react-on-rails` controls how components are loaded.

Another idea: maybe I should only do lazy loading on subcomponents. But I wonder if this will really help decreasing initial load time. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: I just tried this, with lazy, and this works for me, could you provide your react/webpack version ?
Does your component have `default` export?